# How to use a select field's drop-down option value on page load to hide an element with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am hiding some elements based on the current value of a select field with the following JQuery:

```
$('.select').change(function() {
    $(this).parent().siblings('*[class*=hide-if-]').show();
    $(this).parent().siblings('.hide-if-' + $(this).val()).hide();
});
```

And it works fine. (the elements have dynamic classes, for ex. "hide-if-123")

However, I would also like to hide relevant elements when the page loads.
Should I use a different function (instead of "change")?

Or maybe put the code outside the function as well, so it executes on load and on change?
I tried this:

```
$('.select').parent().siblings('.hide-if-' + $('.select').val()).hide();
```

but it doesn't work. I presume I have this part `$('.select').val()` wrong.

It is important that it gets the value of the same select field as the `"select"` in the beginning of the line. I also tried:

```
$('.select').parent().siblings('.hide-if-' + $(this).val()).hide();
```

but still no luck.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to execute your change logic when the page is loaded you can simply trigger the `change` event.

```
$(function() {
  $('.select').trigger('change');
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly! I'm a newbie on JS, in case you haven't noticed, and this tip is a great lesson.

Answer (score 1):

You can just trigger the change handler you've already created:

```
$('.select').change(function() {
     $(this).parent().siblings('*[class*=hide-if-]').show();
     $(this).parent().siblings('.hide-if-' + $(this).val()).hide();
}).change();
```

Calling [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) with no parameters is the equivalent of [`.trigger('change')`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

Though having said that I don't see why your code:

```
$('.select').parent().siblings('.hide-if-' + $('.select').val()).hide();
```

wouldn't work - do all the elements exist when the page first loads? And is the above line included in a document ready handler and/or at the end of the body after the elements in question)?

Comment: Indeed, I thought it should work too and spent two hours figuring out why it wouldn't. Adding the function from the answer below did the trick. Thank you for your time, though, I appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome. Note that you should add your change handler within the document ready (or at the end of the body) - so above where I added the `.change()` call immediately after binding the handler I assumed that was already in a document ready.

Answer (score 0):

add a common class to all the elements and use css to hide them

```
 .hidden-class{ display:none}
```

Benefit is don;t have to wait for script to kick in to make the elements hidden

Comment: The classes are added dynamically. If I hide them with CSS they would become unusable if JS is disabled. Thanks though!